# Powershell function output as [pscustomobject]

Tags: powershell

I am currently working on a function to check for active SQL Server connections. While the function is functional, I find its implementation a bit verbose. Could you provide suggestions or improvements on how to write it more succinctly and efficiently?

```
function get-activeConnection
{
    param(
    [parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$computerName
   )
try
{
$ErrorActionPreference="stop"
$output=[PSCustOmobject]@{
            error  = 0
            count  = 0
            message = ''
}                
try
{
    $SMOServer = New-Object Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.SMO.Server $computerName        
    $ConnectionStr = "Server=$computerName;Database=Master;Integrated Security=True"
    $Query = "EXEC sp_who2" 
    $Connection = new-object system.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $outTable = new-object "System.Data.DataTable" 
    $Connection.connectionstring = $ConnectionStr
    $Connection.open()
    $Command = $Connection.CreateCommand()
    $Command.commandtext = $Query 
    $result = $Command.ExecuteReader() 
    $outTable.Load($result)
    $output.count = ($outTable | where{($_.dbname) -isnot [System.DBNull] -and 
($_.dbname -notin ("master","msdb","model","tempdb","SIT_AdminDB"))}).Rows.Count
    $Connection.close()
}
catch
{
    throw
}
return $output
}
catch
{
    $output.error  = -1
    $output.count  = 0
    $output.message = $Error[0].Exception.Message
    return $output
 } 
}

$computername = "sqlserver1"
$a = get-activeConnection -computerName $computerName 
$a | select *
```